# VueJS select field is not rendered properly when used as a form repeater

Tags: vuejs2

I not able to figure out, why my select field is not loading data? Below is my component and app code.

I am trying to create a form repeater, but only initial select field is initialized properly with filter facility. Also most of the time data in select field does not even load

I need help here

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('product-create', require('./components/ProductCreate.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#product'
})
```

Component vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="box-info full">
          <h2 class="m-0">
            <strong>Add Item</strong>
            <div class="additional-btn"></div>
          </h2>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-1 control-label text-right">Category:</div>
                  <div class="col-md-5 mb-4">
                    <select
                      v-model="selected_option"
                      class="select form-control show-tick form-control"
                    >
                      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                      <option v-for="item in options" v-bind:key="item">
                        {{ item }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div v-if="selected_option === 'Option_1'">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-1 control-label text-right">Client:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-4">
                      <select
                        v-model="product"
                        class="select form-control show-tick"
                        @click="getMoreDetails()"
                      >
                        <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                        <option v-for="item in products" v-bind:key="item">
                          {{ item.name }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

         </div>

            <div v-else>
              <h1>Company</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import apiHelper from "../apiHelper";

export default {
 
  data() {
    return {
      options: ["Option_1", "Option_2"],
      selected_option: "Option_2",
      products : [],
      product: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    initializeData() {
      const response = await apiHelper.getProducts();
      const info = response.data;

      this.products = info;
    },

    getMoreDetails() {
      const response = await apiHelper.getMoreDetails(this.selected_option);
      const info = response.data;
      this.more_details= info;
    },
  },
  created() {
     this.initializeData();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `client` in your `data`

Comment: I have made one edit @AdamOrlov please check now

Comment: I always suggest to try to reproduce the error on codepen or codesandbox. 90% of a time you find your error.

Comment: @AdamOrlov Yes I will try that